# How to sort variables horizontally with arrays and use of call sortc

Tags: sas

A user on sasprofessionals.net had a problem of not being able to group his dataset by several variables where variable values are interchangeable within the observation because they carried the same meaning.

In the example dataset, observation 2,3 and 7 are the same because each of them have A14, A14 and A10 as values for Stat1 to Stat3, and it is only the order is different. These should be grouped by Count. Observation 5 and 6 form another group that should be summed up by count.

Example dataset:

```
Obs Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 Count
1   A14   A14   A14   53090
2   A14   A14   A10   6744
3   A14   A10   A14   5916
4   A01   A01   A01   4222
5   A10   A10   A10   3085
6   A10   A10   A10   2731
7   A10   A14   A14   2399
```

Desirable output:

```
Obs Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 Count
1   A14   A14   A14   53090
4   A01   A01   A01   4222
6   A10   A10   A10   5816
7   A10   A14   A14   15059
```

The actual dataset is larger and more complex. I am not aware if the user tried any methods to solve the problem.

*This question was originally posted on sasprofessionals.net and it was copied to StackOverflow for the benefit of the community. It was changed to meet the StackOverflow Q&A standards.*

Comment: Vasilij, while I think the idea of crossposting information like this is a good one, your question as it stands needs to be a good Stack Overflow question.  Pasting data as a picture is a no-no anywhere, and the question should generally have code in it as well - not just "do this for me".

Comment: In general, I think if you want to do things like this it should be more "basic" concepts; this is really a very specific solution not all that helpful in other cases.  Self answered questions are better off as things you want to point other people to because a lot of people have the same question.  If you want to show the benefits of `sortc`, a simpler question is probably better- simply "how do I sort variables by their values" with a simpler example would be better.  This involves too much other code that will make it hard to understand.

Comment: Hey Joe, fair comment. I will keep that in mind next time. In this specific case, I literally cross posted the question and answer with minimal editing simply because I was thinking it will be beneficial to some users as is without investing a lot of time into editing it or changing outright.

Comment: I understand, but it still has to be valid for StackOverflow in its own right.

Comment: Sorry, you went from "good Stack Overflow question" to "valid for Stack Overflow". Which one is it? Is my question valid or not very brialliant but still ok? :)

Comment: Well, right now it's not a valid stack overflow question really - in my book self-answered ones like this should be _good_, but at least have to be _valid_.  It's not off topic, it's just a question that if it were asked *de noveau* it would probably be downvoted because it's just asking for code (and has data in a picture).  I suppose I'm mixing terms to some extent though.  SO is too much of a wilderness to have the common meaning of 'valid' I guess :)

Comment: I will go with what you are saying and edit the question to get it into format that you are suggesting. I will ask you to review it and recommend any improvements. I am a new member here and new members should be learning from more experienced members of the community.
I will get it done tomorrow, I don't have time for it today.

Comment: Thanks!  @ping me so I notice it as this will probably fall down some.

Comment: Hey Joe, I don't know how to "ping" you, so I am going to leave a comment on here. If you get to check the answer, let me know if you think it meets the standards and how I could improve it. Cheers, Vasilij

Comment: I think the ping would be @Joe

Comment: Hey @Joe, let me know if you think it meets the standards and how I could improve it. Cheers, Vasilij

Comment: With the edits, I think it's a good question.  I browse a lot to learn new approaches, techniques, functions etc... I wasn't familiar with the `sortc` function, so the question/answer now benefited me outright.  I now have a new tool in my toolbox.

Comment: @VasilijNevlev Thanks!  The only other thing is i'd leave a link to the sasprofessionals question, if that's possible (I'm not familiar with the forum myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my answer to solve the user's problem. In general, I loaded Stat1-Stat3 into an array, sorted the array with sortc call function and then summed it up by a temporary ID which was constructed out of sorted Stat1-Stat3 array.

```
/* Loading the data into SAS dataset */ 
/* Loading Stat1-Stat3 into an array */
/* Sorting stat1-stat3 creating a new ID */
data have; 
input obs stat1 $ stat2 $ stat3 $ count; 
array stat{3} stat1-stat3;
call sortc(of stat1-stat3); 
ID = CATX("/",stat1,stat2,stat3);
datalines; 
1 A14 A14 A14 53090
2 A14 A14 A10 6744
3 A14 A10 A14 5916
4 A01 A01 A01 4222
5 A10 A10 A10 3085
6 A10 A10 A10 2731
7 A10 A14 A14 2399
; 


/* sorting the data set in preparation for data step with by statement*/
PROC SORT data=have; 
BY ID OBS; 
RUN; 

/* Summarising the dataset and outputing into final dataset*/
DATA summed (drop=ID count); 
set sorted_arrays; 
by ID; 
retain sum 0; 
if first.ID then sum = 0; 
sum + count; 
if last.ID then output; 
RUN; 

/* Sorting it back into original order */
PROC SORT data=summed out=want; 
BY OBS; 
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I've been giving myself hash exercises, I decided to try this via hashing.  Paul Dorfman has a couple papers that discuss using hash tables to sort an array, e.g. [Black Belt Hashigana](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/023-2010.pdf).

Below, I use one hash table to sort horizontally, then another hash table to sum the counts by ID.  The data only have to be read once, but given the size of the data I'm certainly not claiming an efficiency benefit in this case.  I didn't return the data back to original sort order.

Edits/questions/suggestions welcome, as this is part of my hash learning curve. : )

```
data have; 
input stat1 $ stat2 $ stat3 $ count; 
datalines; 
A14 A14 A14 53090
A14 A14 A10 6744
A14 A10 A14 5916
A01 A01 A01 4222
A10 A10 A10 3085
A10 A10 A10 2731
A10 A14 A14 2399
; 

data want;
  length _stat $3;

  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash  hstat(multidata:"y", ordered:"y");
    declare hiter hstatiter ("hstat" ) ;      
    hstat.definekey('_stat');
    hstat.definedata('_stat'); 
    hstat.definedone();
    call missing(_stat);

    declare hash  hsum(suminc: "count", ordered: "y");
    declare hiter hsumiter ("hsum" ) ;      
    hsum.definekey("stat1","stat2","stat3");
    hsum.definedone();
  end;

  set have end=last;

  array stat{3};

  *load the array values into htable hstat to sort them;
  *then iterate over the hash, returning the values to array in sorted order;
  do _i=1 to dim(stat);  
    hstat.add(key:stat{_i},data:stat{_i});
  end;
  do _i=1 to dim(stat);
    hstatiter.next();
    stat{_i}=_stat;
  end;
  _rc=hstatiter.next(); *hack- there is no next, this releases hiter lock so can clear hstat;
  hstat.clear();

  *now that the stat keys have been sorted, can use them as key in hash table hsum;
  *as data are loaded into/checked against the hash table, counts are summed;
  *Then if last, iterate over hsum writing it to output dataset;

  hsum.ref(); *This sums count as records are loaded/checked;

  if last then do;
    _rc = hsumiter.next();
    do while(_rc = 0);
      _rc = hsum.sum(sum: count);
      output ;
      _rc = hsumiter.next();
    end;
  end;

  drop _: ;
run;
```